# How to insert multi data in laravel6.0

Tags: laravel

Here is my View.

```
 @foreach($units as $unit)
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="name{{$unit -> id}}" value="{{$unit -> name}}"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="value{{$unit -> id}}" value="{{$unit -> value}}"/></td>
      <td><button onclick = "delete(this)"></button></td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

When I post it, I want to insert all data in database.
Problem is that we may delete one colume in table tag.

So we can use `for()` or `foreach()` in Controller. 
So I tried to do like this.
I post the `id` of `unit` as Array.
And in Controller, I used `for()` and tried to get tag name like this.

```
 for ($k = 1; $k <= count($unitArray); $k++){
        $unitType = new UnitType();
        $unitTypeName = 'unitTypeName-' . $k;
        $unitTypeValue = 'unitTypeValue-' . $k;
        $unitType -> name = $request->input($unitTypeName);
        $unitType -> value = $request->input($unitTypeValue);
        $unitType -> save();
    }
```

But I did not get success.
Please let me know if you have good solution.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
We can use same name for several input tags and they post as an array to controller.
So we can use it.

```
 @foreach($units as $unit)
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="{{$unit -> name}}"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="value[]" value="{{$unit -> value}}"/></td>
  <td><button onclick = "delete(this)"></button></td>
</tr>
 @endforeach
```

And In controller.

```
 $name = $request -> name;
 $value = $request -> value;
 for($i = 0; $i<count($name);$i++){
   $unit=new UnitType();
   $unit->name=$name[$i];
   $unit->value=$value[$i];
   $unit->save();
 }
```

Thank you again Mr.David.

Answer (score 0):

That's my simple solution, your input name is not mapping.

```
 for ($k = 1; $k <= count($unitArray); $k++){
    $unitType = new UnitType();
    $unitTypeName = 'name' . $k;
    $unitTypeValue = 'value-' . $k;
    $unitType -> name = $request->input($unitTypeName);
    $unitType -> value = $request->input($unitTypeValue);
    $unitType -> save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you effort.Mr.David.
It's not working on my pc.